# How does flowing consumer work in node rdkafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using flowing mode consumer of [rdkafka](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka) with my node application. I want to fetch only few number of messages at a time. Does it keep fetching messages and buffer them in a queue? If yes, then can we change this configuration and put a limit on the number of messages fetched?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about rdkafka but in java client there is a config to limit the no. of records fetched in one poll operation.

[max.poll.records](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the consumer fetches messages into a queue, until the queued messages reach a certain limit.

Try using this property in your consumer's config:

```
{
  //...
  'queued.max.messages.kbytes': 1024
  //Maximum number of kilobytes per topic + partition in the local consumer queue
  //...
}
```

This property is documented [here](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md#global-configuration-properties)